# Testing Android Studio Apps on Hardware Device

Tags: android, debugging

I have just started to develop android apps.
My computer does not have a great graphics card so I use my phone to debug apps.
But when I run the app in android studio and select my phone, the app runs but it just shows a blank button on the top left hand corner whereas the original app has much more than that.

xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" 
       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
       android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
       android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
       tools:context=".MainActivity" android:id="@+id/myapp" 
       android:background="#ff0060"> 
  <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Hello World" 
       android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

I am attaching the screenshots to make it more clear. Please Help!

[image]

Comment: can u add some of your code?

Comment: xml file and  landing activity

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/myapp"
    android:background="#ff0060">

Comment: <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

Comment: They don't allow to post comments that long. But I have tried to post the main part of the code.

Comment: as in ur xml shows u add only a single button in your activity.. so it shows only single button in phone

Comment: But the text does not appear on the button. Also I have set the background color to pink which also doesn't show up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93125/discussion-between-ayusch-jain-and-shivanshu-verma).

Comment: Pleasem ake sure AndroidManifest file where you declare your activity properly or not..

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/myapp">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:text="Hello World"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="#ff0060" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

change youe xml file with this code